# do_div equivalent in userspace (glibc)

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, glibc

Does glibc have an equivalent for the Kernel macro as under:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/div64.h#L40

I am trying to write a user-space binary (glibc) to attain the same functionality. Is it possible ?

Thanks,
vj

Answer (score 0):

I Think you're searching for the [div()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/div) function. But it returns a div_t struct which contains the quotient and remainder.

Maybe you prefer using [remainder()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/remainder) depends of your needs.